# Why is this db/seeds.db creating 29200 microposts records? This is way more than expected. RoR Hartl Tutorial 11.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake, railstutorial.org, seeding

Ok, so I've been working my way through the beautiful Hartl Tutorial we all love - I'm stuck on a particular issue. Ch 11.2, very end - we've just built the seed and migration for basic user posting data, but he and I get different results.

I have the following in my db/seeds.db:

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
  end
```

I'll run a rake:reset and it generates a table with 100 users and 29200 microposts total. This number is clearly way too high. I don't understand what's going on entirely, where can I find more debugging info?

Here's my current branch repo:

https://github.com/kfrz/sample_app/tree/user-microposts

Thanks for any help!

Comment: My /log/development.log is 47M alone - https://gist.github.com/kfrz/8b7bbe685ca09c57fc8a

There's an example of the queries. Should i worry about the "?" in VALUES?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)
50.times do
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence(5)
  users.each { |user| user.microposts.create!(content: content) }
end
```

is iside of your `99.times do |n| ... end` just move the end from the end of your file to line 28.

Comment: Thank you very much! Obvious now, for some reason slipped past my eyes 20x. 

This is why I need a pair programmer.